# Correct set notation regarding bit strings

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, bit-strings

Let's say we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} &= \{0000,0101,0011,0010\}\\
\mathcal{B} &= \{1100,1001\}\\
\mathcal{R} &= \{0011,0010\}
\end{align*}

Using set notations, how do I express set $R$, that is actually all the elements of $A$ subtracted from $B$, if any of the elements in $A$ has the last two bits common with $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you mean is $\mathcal{R}=\{a\in\mathcal{A}|\neg\exists b\in\mathcal{B}((a_3,\,a_4)=(b_3,\,b_4))\}$, where I index the leftmost bit in each string as bit $1$. This says $\mathcal{R}$ is the set of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ that don't have the same last two bits as any element of $\mathcal{B}$.

The first $=$ is [set equality in the sense of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality); the second $=$ abbreviates $a_3=a_4,\,b_3=b_4$, regardless of your favoured definition of [ordered tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair).

Comment: is '=' a formal term that can be used here? Also can you please use words to describe this?

Comment: @svetlana See edit.